# Dual-boot for System76 Ubuntu computer

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I'm planning to buy a [system76](https://system76.com/) desktop computer this year. These systems come pre-installed with Ubuntu. I know I might be forced sometimes to use Windows. I don't want to touch anything from the original HDD, so I have these questions:

1. Is it possible to add a hard drive?
2. Only when I need it to boot Windows?
3. And if it is, do you have instruction in how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. (Not on some of the laptops, just to be complete if you change your mind later on)
2. No, Windows cannot boot from an "additional" hard drive: **Windows MUST boot from the first partition on the first hard drive**. (And it has been like this from DOS 2.11, the first DOS I used.  Microsoft has a near-monopoly and can *dictate* how things must be done!)
3. Yes:  There *is* a way to "fool" Windows that it's booting from the first partition on the first hard drive by changing BIOS settings (but it *cannot* be an external (USB) HDD).  As this site is about Ubuntu, the *exact details* for this Windows tomfoolery is better asked on http://superuser.com, a sister-site of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: 2. - is no longer true.  The Grub boot loader will log an entry for Windows when it detects it.  I have Ubuntu one SSD (installed first), then installed Win7 on a second SSD.  Run 'update-grub' and that's it.  On boot, Grub gives lists the options for which OS to boot into.

Comment: @nullsteph Try booting Windows 7 without grub from the second hard drive... (I tried up to Windows 10 RC1)